# Oracle EBS direct database access

Tags: oracle-ebs

We have a client who are using Oracle EBS. They would like to build some API to retrieve the data from Oracle EBS database through JDBC directly, and read the data through the API and insert into another database for another mobile application. Do we need to buy another Oracle EBS name user license? Or we just need to buy one Oracle database user license. 
Why I asked this, because in SAP world, it seems directly access database will need per access name user license. Not sure, it is the same in Oracle EBS.
Please advice, and correct me if anything wrong.

Best regards,

Comment: I did work for a fairly well known firm which regularly required accessing the EBS database and processing the database data to extract access reports. I believe all you need is the required Oracle DB licensing which you likely already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have them talk to their sales rep.  Generally, the Oracle database is licenced on a CPU basis (not named user basis).  But there are certain technology features that may only be licensed for EBS use.

It sounds like you are using a different user to access data, which is the correct approach from a security perspective.  Make sure that that database user has only the database privileges required to extract the data the application requires (least privs).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, we will let the client to ask the sales rep then.

Comment: I don't think you need any license. If you have access to the Oracle EBS database, you can access the data using JDBC. Alternatively, you can create APIs using JSP, ORDS, or other methods to expose the data."